# PDFBox display hexa codes instead of content

Tags: pdfbox, letters

I am using PDFBox to parse a large amount of files and the problem is that for two files, the output contains only hexadecimal digits (0-9A-F). For example, the word "Datum:" is represented as "123456". Is there any way to get the correct content of the files (the files were created with GPL Ghostscript v9.xx)?

Thank you in advance!